# Update image with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello friends of the community, I'm uploading an image to the MySQL database, I have no problem everything works fine.
But when I update the image goes blank as you can see in this picture:
[image]

This is the code I use to update records:

```
public function update($id,$fname,$lname,$email,$contact,$imagen,$fecha)
    {
        try
        {
            if(!empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])){
                $nnombre=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
                $ruta=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
                $destino =  "img/productos/".$nnombre;
                $imagen = $nnombre;
                copy($ruta, $destino);
            }

            $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE productos SET first_name=:fname, 
                                                       last_name=:lname, 
                                                       email_id=:email, 
                                                       contact_no=:contact,
                                                       imagen=:imagen,
                                                       fecha=:fecha
                                                    WHERE id=:id");

            $stmt->bindparam(":fname",$fname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lname",$lname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":contact",$contact);
            $stmt->bindparam(":imagen",$imagen, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(":fecha",$fecha);
            $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
            $stmt->execute();

            return true;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
            return false;
        }
    }
```

All it updated, but the image does not update.

I should do, please.

Comment: only update your image when there is an actual image uploaded.  when there is no image, you should not include it on your `prepare statement` and remove it on your `bindParam`

Comment: oks, solve my problem :) if!empty{ I put in my code variable image } else{ in my code not put the variable image }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this one

```
$stmt->bindparam(":imagen",$imagen, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

use

```
$stmt->bindparam(":imagen",$imagen, PDO::PARAM_BLOB);
```

Then, it will work fine.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP's code snippet because the `$imagen` variable contain only the name of the file and not the whole file.